# input field with variable name, how to get the posted values?

Tags: php, arrays, post, input

I have a form containing names from an array, with each name having the possibility to pick a radio button options 5,10,20 and 50.

my code contains this:

```
 $names = $names;  
    foreach ($names as $name)   
    {        
         // some div and html coding
         "<input type='radio' name='".$name[0]."' value='5'>"; 
         "<input type='radio' name='".$name[0]."' value='10'>"; 
         "<input type='radio' name='".$name[0]."' value='20'>"; 
         "<input type='radio' name='".$name[0]."' value='50'>"; 
         // some other html and closing tags
    }
```

Example of how the page looks like:

[image: sceenshot]

My question:

How can I get the posted values?

Let's say `name2` and `name4` option `10` are selected and `name5` option `20`, how do I get the posted values into an array that looks like this:

```
$result = array(
    "name2" => "10",
    "name4" => "10", 
    "name5" => "20"
);
```

thanks alot!

Comment: just remove the `[0]` index from input name, like this : `"<input type='radio' name='".$name."' value='5'>";`  Then check the posted data

Comment: Change it like that `name='myradio[".$name."]'` and then just access `print_r($_POST['myradio']);`

Comment: I treid that, but then then i can only pick one number and not a number for each name , then all values become part of the same radio button.

Comment: Arent the values in `$names` not different? Better post the created html here.

Comment: @Roddeh and plz say to witch comment you reply here, thnx

Comment: actually, that answer works for both @justonundermillions

Comment: aight, i just needed to add brackets in order to get the radio buttons not interfere, like this: 'myradio[".$name[0]."]'

Answer (score 1):

instead of using foreach()

you should use for loop as follow

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST)){
    $names=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
        if(in_array($_POST[$key], $names))
        # code...
            echo 'Do Your Logic Here  ';
    }
}
?>

<form action="s.php" method='post'>
<?php

for($i = 0; $i <= count($names) ; $i++){
    echo "<input type='radio' name='".$names[$i]."' value='5'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='".$names[$i]."' value='10'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='".$names[$i]."' value='20'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='".$names[$i]."' value='50'>";
}

    echo "<input type='submit' />";


 ?>
 </form>
```

this should fix your issue

Answer (score -1):

```
    try this..
     <php $names = $names;?> 
       <form method="post">
      <php
     foreach ($names as $name)   
       {        
     // some div and html coding
     "<input type='radio' name='name[".$name."]' value='5'>"; 
     "<input type='radio' name='name[".$name."]' value='10'>"; 
     "<input type='radio' name='name[".$name."]' value='20'>"; 
     "<input type='radio' name='name[".$name."]'' value='50'>"; 
     // some other html and closing tags
   } ?>
  <input type="submit" />
   </form>
```

Comment: Sry, but what is the return value of `$name[]` here?